# Loop through a firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am new to programming.

I have a firebase realtime database. My intent is to get data from the realtime database when a condition is met. That means using a loop statement.

Here is the code:

```
    function firestore(agent) {
    var firebaseEntity = agent.parameters.firebase;
    return admin.database().ref('questions').once("value").then((snapshot) => {
        var questionList = snapshot.child("Entity").val();
            for (const i in questionList) {
              if (questionList[i].entity == firebaseEntity);
                var response = questionList[i].response;
    agent.add(`${response}`);
}
});
}
```

I want to return 'response' when the user's input matches the 'question' column:
[image: I want to return 'response' when the user's input matches the 'question' column]

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. You are using the Realtime Database and **not** Cloud Firestore. I removed the tag from your question already, but recommend you also update your code to remove the reference to Firestore in the function name, to prevent future./further confusion.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. There is no `Entity` node under `/questions`, so your `questionList` will always be empty.
2. There is not even an `Entity` node under each individual question, as it's called `entity` with a lowercase `e`.
3. I recommend using Firebase's built-in `forEach` function to iterate over the child nodes, instead of `for... in`.

So with those:

```
function firestore(agent) {
  var firebaseEntity = agent.parameters.firebase;
  return admin.database().ref('questions').once("value").then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((questionSnapshot) => {
      let question = questionSnapshot.val();
      if (question.entity == firebaseEntity) {
        cont response = question.response;
        agent.add(`${response}`);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I wanted clarity on the lines after the 'if' statement. For example, 'questionList[i]' is not defined.

Comment: I fixed that syntax error too. Please try to fix other small problems yourself before posting though, as some self-sufficiency is expected here.